# JavaScript to select multiple select list values

Tags: javascript

I have the following select list from which the user can select multiple values.

```
<select name="valumethod1[]" id="valumethod1[]"  onBlur="validatevalumethod()" size="6">
     <option value ="t1">test1</option>
     <option value ="t2">test2</option>
     <option value ="t3">test3</option>
     <option value ="t4">test4</option>
</select>
```

I want to fetch the selected values in JavaScript, but I don't know how to do this. Please help me.

Comment: just one word user493619 - ACCEPT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this :

```
var ob = document.getElementById('valumethod1[]');
var selected = new Array();
for (var i = 0; i < ob.options.length; i++) {
  if (ob.options[ i ].selected) {
      selected.push(ob.options[ i ].value);
  }
}
```

The array `selected` is then an array of selected options. [Working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/nNw5Z/)

Note: you need to add `multiple="multiple"` to your `select` list as an attribute

Comment: really thanks for the reply. can you please help me if i want to check for each selected value with one of predefined variable in javascript and if it get match then display one alert message to user.

Comment: yes i have implement the solution y r provided it really helpful to me

Comment: sorry because i dont have enough knowledge, now is it accepted

Comment: @user493619 ok - perfect - you should accept answers from **all** of the questions you ask

Comment: yes you teach me both javascript as well as how to accept answer thanks